# Recalculate When Macro Changes Data Validation

Tags: excel, vba

I have a series of data validation fields that I am using a macro to switch back and forth.

When the macro sets the value of the data validation field, the workbook won't catch up by updating the worksheet.

I have checked that the calculations are set to automatic. I have tried to recalculate the worksheet after every selection.

```
Sub generate_indications()
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Filing Indication Selections").Range("H:K").ClearContents
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Dim filing_sheet As Worksheet
    Dim selection_sheet As Worksheet
    Dim indication As Double
    Set filing_sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Filing Indication")
    Set selection_sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Filing Indication Selections")
    For Each ind_option In selection_sheet.Range("A:A")
        'filing_sheet.EnableCalculation = False
        If selection_sheet.Cells(ind_option.Row, 1) = "" Then
            'filing_sheet.EnableCalculation = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
        With filing_sheet
            .Range("A7").Value = selection_sheet.Cells(ind_option.Row, 1).Value 'Capped/Uncapped
            If selection_sheet.Cells(ind_option.Row, 2).Value = "N/A" Then
                'Set to 250K by default, though this won't affect the calculation
                .Range("A6").Value = "250K"
            Else
                .Range("A6").Value = selection_sheet.Cells(ind_option.Row, 2).Value '250K or 100K
            End If
            .Range("A8").Value = selection_sheet.Cells(ind_option.Row, 3).Value 'Paid/Incurred
            If selection_sheet.Cells(ind_option.Row, 4).Value = "CW Loss Trend" Then
                'Select the CW version
                .Range("A9").Value = selection_sheet.Cells(ind_option.Row, 4).Value
            Else
                .Range("A9").Value = .Range("L7").Value & " Loss Trend" 'Select the State Loss Trend
            End If
            .Range("A10").Value = selection_sheet.Cells(ind_option.Row, 5).Value 'Bureau/Farmers LDF
            If selection_sheet.Cells(ind_option.Row, 5).Value = "Bureau LDF" Then
                'Choose option for 2yr vs 5yr
                If Left(selection_sheet.Cells(ind_option.Row, 6).Value, 1) = 2 Then
                    .Range("A18").Value = "2 Yr Bureau"
                Else
                    .Range("A18").Value = "5 Yr Bureau"
                End If

            Else
                'Choose option 1-5 yr
                If Left(selection_sheet.Cells(ind_option.Row, 6).Value, 1) = 1 Then
                    .Range("A12").Value = "1 Yr Ave"
                ElseIf Left(selection_sheet.Cells(ind_option.Row, 6).Value, 1) = 2 Then
                    .Range("A12").Value = "2 Yr Ave"
                ElseIf Left(selection_sheet.Cells(ind_option.Row, 6).Value, 1) = 3 Then
                    .Range("A12").Value = "3 Yr Ave"
                ElseIf Left(selection_sheet.Cells(ind_option.Row, 6).Value, 1) = 4 Then
                    .Range("A12").Value = "4 Yr Ave"
                ElseIf Left(selection_sheet.Cells(ind_option.Row, 6).Value, 1) = 4 Then
                    .Range("A12").Value = "5 Yr Ave"
                Else
                    .Range("A12").Value = "Default"
                End If
            End If
            If selection_sheet.Cells(ind_option.Row, 7).Value = "CW Compliment" Then
                .Range("A11").Value = "CW LT Compliment"
            ElseIf selection_sheet.Cells(ind_option.Row, 7).Value = "Standard" Then
                .Range("A11").Value = "Standard Compliment"
            Else
                .Range("A11").Value = .Range("L7").Value & " LT Compliment"
            End If
            'filing_sheet.EnableCalculation = True
            .Calculate
            indication = .Range("I41").Value
            complement = .Range("I40").Value
            credibility = .Range("I39").Value
            preZ = .Range("I38").Value
        End With
        selection_sheet.Cells(ind_option.Row, 8).Value = indication
        selection_sheet.Cells(ind_option.Row, 9).Value = complement
        selection_sheet.Cells(ind_option.Row, 10).Value = credibility
        selection_sheet.Cells(ind_option.Row, 11).Value = preZ

    Next ind_option
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve with `.EnableCalculation` - try using `Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link to a similar issue may help or it may not.

[Excel VBA - worksheet.calculate doesn't calculate all of my formulas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25687320/excel-vba-worksheet-calculate-doesnt-calculate-all-of-my-formulas)

I didn't see anywhere that you were defining an active sheet in your code or a loop that is looping through each active sheet for calculations.